# How to trigger function for button in every row with person name from that row?

Tags: python, templates, tornado

I am using Tornado and default template engine with Tornado. In code I am trying to call request_func with name of person (every row has different person with probably different name) but it doesn't trigger at all.

```
        {% for h  in people %}
                    <tr valign="middle">
                        <td style='text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;'> {{h['rank']}} </td>

                        <td style='text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;'> {{h['name']}} </td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;'> 
                            {% if h['nation'] == player_data['nation'] %}
                                <a data-role="button" class="custom-button" onclick="request_func({{h['name']}})">Request Nation Friend</a>
                            {% end %}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% end %}
```

Can anyone help me how to trigger function for button in every row with person name from that row ?
Person name is passed from python to template.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery, you can put something like it

```
<a data-role="button" class="custom-button" name="request" data-name="{{h['name']}}">Request Nation Friend</a>
```

and on head

```
<script languange="Javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('a[name=request]').click(function() {
       alert("MY name is " + $(this).data('name'));
    });
  });
</script>
```